# Ajax call into java getting a "#document" rather than a useful list of objects

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on a service that is working perfectly when deployed into test environments.

I open the web page, and the javascript call is made as so:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: url,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      displaySummaryText(xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function(returnData) {
      displayRequestSummaryData(returnData, start);
    }
})
```

The result comes back as so:

```
returnData
(397) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}..etc
```

The returnData contains an array of maps, with the data from the java objects mapped into a pojo.

However when I take that same service (with a few unrelated changes) and run it up in my local environment I get very different behaviour, it appears in the javascript debugger as:

```
#document
```

length, [0], etc on this all return undefined.

If I view the returned object in the browser's console I see

```
<List><item><date/><time/><sym/><id>Valid data here</id><userId/><userRequestId/></item> 
</List>
```

Which does contain what I'm expecting to see in this case - but it seems to be as xml/text inside a #document object rather than having been parsed.

What would cause this behaviour where javascript does not seem to be trying to parse the response from the ajax call?

Comment: That's an error message emitted by the *server*, so you need to look at your server-side code.

Comment: Seems like the API is responding with a 200 status when it should be a 404

Comment: @Quentin Updated the example to be clear that the server is responding with a list of a single valid item (that happened to include a not found message) - but the javascript is not processing it as an object.

Comment: @Phil Updated the example to be clear that the server is responding with a list of a single valid item (that happened to include a not found message) - but the javascript is not processing it as an object.

Comment: Look at your server code to determine why it is responding with XML instead of JSON. Probably you are processing some header (`Accept`, `Content-Type`) differently…

Comment: @Bergi that was exactly it! thanks (see answer I just posted)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @bergi in the comments this was happening because the server was responding with XML rather than JSON and javascript was not parsing that.

I added  `produces = "application/json")` to the Get Mapping annotation to force it to Json and immediately it started working correctly.